# Use WillCascadeOnDelete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have entity class:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Menu> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and confige class :

```
public class MenuConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Menu>
{
    public MenuConfig()
    {
        HasOptional(x => x.Parent).WithMany(x =>x.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(x=>x.ParentID).WillCascadeOnDelete();
        Property(x => x.Title).HasMaxLength(200);
    }
}
```

how use WillCascadeOnDelete in model?

The exception message is the following one:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Menus_dbo.Menus_ParentID' on table 'Menus'           may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO    ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>       Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use cascading on self-related entities. It's just not possible.

**UPDATE:**

See why not:

```
obj1.Children = obj2, obj3
obj2.Children = obj4, obj5
obj5.Children = obj1, someOtherObjs

deleting obj1 -----------<-----------
    should delete obj2              |
        should delete obj5          |
            should delete obj1 -->---
```

and yep, you are in a cycle.

Comment: tancks for answer...You can suggest a better solution?